# "`<main>': uninitialized constant MPI (NameError)" in Ruby debian

Tags: ruby, mpi, openmpi

Problem description
I am trying to run ruby code, I am also importing MPI in it. but I am getting the error

```
PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643
 NINTERVALS = 10000
     
$rank = MPI::Comm::WORLD.rank()
$size = MPI::Comm::WORLD.size()
$startwtime = MPI.wtime()
$h = 1.0 / NINTERVALS
$sum = 0.0
($rank + 1).step(NINTERVALS, $size) do |i|
        x = $h * (i - 0.5)
        $sum += (4.0 / (1.0 + x**2))
end
mypi = $h * $sum
 
$pi = MPI::Comm::WORLD.reduce(mypi, MPI::Op::SUM, 0)
if $rank == 0 then
        printf "pi is ~= %.16f, error = %.16f\n", $pi, ($pi - PI25DT).abs
        $endwtime = MPI.wtime()
        puts "wallclock time = #{$endwtime-$startwtime}"
end
```

Please help, It looks the problem is with MPI, how can I resolve it.

Comment: Is this your complete program, or did you show here only part of it? You are, as the error message clearly says,  using a constant `MPI`, but don't provide a definition for it. How is Ruby supposed to know, what `MPI` means?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using https://github.com/gfd-dennou-club/ruby-mpi. There are no docs that demonstrate usage like what you have here, but I would guess that adding `require 'ruby-mpi'` as the first line of your program would fix it.

Comment: @user1934428 it a complete program and I installed MPI libraries already but I guess I did some mistake somewhere in .bashrc while defining this path. Do you have any idea? what exactly I need to change

Comment: @anothermh  I tried this but not working :-(

Comment: @Robot : I don't see a `require` statement in your code which would drag in the libraries. Do you think just installing them makes them visible, like magic? And if you add the necessary `require` (please show it in your code), do you still get the **same** error message?